# How can the Apache 2.2 deflate_module length limit be increased?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-deflate

I came across a problem with deflating HTML files larger than 8000 characters (documented in  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591157/what-is-limiting-html-page-size-to-8000-characters/9592079#9592079) at stackoverflow). A straight HTML file larger than that causes the server to fail to deliver the contents resulting in the browser giving a 'server reset connection' message or something similar.

If I disable compression for the directory in question by removing the line containing 'SetOutputFilter DEFLATE' then the size limit is removed, but of course pages are not then compressed. [This Apache document](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) states that the default deflate buffer size is 8KB, which corresponds roughly to the size limit I am reaching, but adding the line 'DeflateBufferSize 20480' makes no difference to the size of page that can be compressed so I guess that is not the parameter I need to add or change.

Output generated by server side includes or AJAX calls is often far larger than 8000 characters and is compressed without problems. It is only with a straight HTML file that I am experiencing issues.

How can I increase the size of file that module deflate will compress?

EDIT:I did not find an answer beyond disabling mod_deflate, instead I put the HTML into another file and used a Server Side Include to display it. Not ideal, but it gets the job done and the page isn't part of the main project.

Answer (score 0):

According to the "module documentation":http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html the `DeflateBufferSize` directive doesn't control the size of files which may be deflated, but instead the size of the *fragments* being deflated. The larger files (i.e. the AJAX calls you cite) are getting fragmented and compressed in fragments.

I'm guessing the error is due to something other than `mod_deflate`.

Comment: I agree about DeflateBufferSize but it was the only parameter that seemed even vaguely connected with the issue we are experiencing. Anyway, I have a workaround (using SSI) so it's not a critical issue anymore, I'd still be interested in seeing any possible causes.

Comment: I could well be something other than mod_deflate, but taking out that line from the directory config allowed the page to be displayed so that led me to believe it was the problem.